# Buttons are unclickable swift

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I've got a problem with two of my buttons in my Xcode project. After adding two views above them to create a border around them they cannot be clicked anymore. After removing them again the buttons work but adding the back causes them to not work.

Here's my view hierarchy in my project:

Before:

```
-mainView
 -scrollView
  -contentView
   -stackView
    -stackView
     -stackView
      -stackView
       -Button1
       -Button2
```

After:

```
-mainView
 -scrollView
  -contentView
   -stackView
    -stackView
     -stackView
      -stackView
       -uiView (new View)
        -uiView (new View)
         -Button1
       -uiView (new View)
        -uiView (new View)
         -Button2
```

Is it because there are too many views?

Thank you very much, if you need any more pieces of information just write a comment and I'll try to help in the next edit.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a view on top of the button?

Comment: @Shades No, both of them are inside of the views like I displayed it above.

Comment: Check that user interaction is *enabled* for those views

Comment: It already was...

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Usually this problem is either caused by something (including UIViews and Stackviews, and of course the button itself) having interaction disabled, or the button not actually being in the hierarchy so the view is on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got the solution now...
It worked after setting the `Alignment` and `Distribution` of the StackView to `Fill`

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UIView` as a `PassthroughView` and set the class of your newly added views to be `PassthroughView`. Add this code:

```
class PassthroughView: UIView {
  override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return subviews.contains(where: { !$0.isHidden && $0.point(inside: point, with: event)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It passes the touch through the superview of each button.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work but I might have found another way so that I won't need to use a button at all but by using one of the views as a button with a Tap Gesture Recognizer.